# How do I bind a property to the main application component?

Tags: angular, angular6

How do I bind a property of a component on my application to a property of app.component?

For example, my app.component.html consists of the following:

```
<app-type #typeComponent></app-type>

<app-search #searchComponent [propX]="typeComponent.someProp3"></app-search>

<app-results [propA]="searchComponent.someProp1"></app-results>
```

How do I bind to a property of `<app-search>` to a value found in app.component? How do I bind to app.component? In the case of `[propX]="typeComponent.someProp3"` I'm binding to `someProp3` of `typeComponent` but I don't see how to bind to `app.component`.

Comment: If you want to set `propX` to `myValue` of `appComponent`, you can do this: `<app-search [propX]="myValue">`. The default context is the parent component instance (you can also use `this.myValue` but `this` is not needed).

Comment: @ConnorsFan - I tried that earlier but it didn't work. Now it seems to be working just fine. If you want, paste into an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default context](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context) for [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) is the parent component instance. Therefore, given a parent component with the property `appValue`:

```
export class AppComponent {
    public appValue = "Hello world!";
}
```

you can bind the property `propX` of a child component to `appValue` with the following syntax:

```
<app-search [propX]="appValue" ...>
```